# How to ensure that the x and y range are the same?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm making a bubble chart (http://jsfiddle.net/6tc6T/138/) and I'd like to force the X and Y axes to match each other. I could do this by setting the min and max values for each axis, but that would lock it in. When I pull the "Bronx" series off the chart, the chart zooms in. I'd like to retain the ability to zoom but keep the axes constant.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'bubble',
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },

        series: [{
            name: "Bronx",
            data: [{"station": "East 143 St-St Mary's St ", 'x': 771, 'y': 973, 'z': 1744 }, {"station": "Morris Park ", 'x': 1255, 'y': 2083, 'z': 3338 }]
        }, {
            name: "Queens",
            data: [{"station": "Broad Channel  ", 'x': 171, 'y': 267, 'z': 438 }]
        }]

    });

});
```

Any leads on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Possibly could catch this in `redraw()`, but there may be a cleaner way than this.

Comment: So labels on xAxis should be the same values after zoom or I am wrong?

Comment: After zoom, the xAxis and the yAxis should match each other.

Comment: Updated to fix the URL, too. Sorry about that!

Comment: Have you tried to use setExtremes() funciton or catch setExtrees event? http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes() http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.events.setExtremes